# Modifying base::quit defaults

Tags: r, dotfiles

I would like to update my `.Rprofile` to modify `base::quit`. The normal behavior of `q` and `quit` is to prompt you to ask if you'd like to save your workspace. I would like to modify these functions so that they default to not saving my workspace,<sup>1</sup> e.g., by modifying the functions as below:

```
q <- function(save = "no") {
    quit(save = save)
}
quit <- function(save = "no") {
    quit(save = save)
}
```

There's a problem here, however. (I'm a little new to `R`, so my description may not be perfectly accurate.) The functions `q` and `quit` are added to the global environment. As a result, if I call `ls()`, these functions will be included. Adding in the following code

```
environment(q) <- as.environment("package:base")
```

seems to add `q` to the `base` namespace. That is, I see the following:

```
# > q
# function(save = "no", ...)
# {
#     quit(save = save), ...)
# }
# <environment: base>
```

However, when I call `ls()`, `q` and `quit` both still appear, and if I call `rm(list = ls())` then both `q` and `quit` revert to their original definitions in `base`.

What should I be doing to avoid this behavior? I would like `q` and `quit` to be modified so that they only appear when I call `ls(name = "package:base")`.

---

<sub>1 <sub>There are a few reasons for this. I often run R from the command line to inspect data files in directories where I’d like to be able to count on every file being a data file, and so don't want any dotfiles cluttering the directory.  Moreover, any analysis or cleaning I do in the console is not likely to be reproducible.</sub></sub>

Comment: Well, if this is all because you want to use `rm(list=ls())`, then that's probably the problem. That's not a command you should really have to run that often. Is there a reason you need to do that? Sounds like you probably have other variable scoping problems. You can't make a custom function disappear from the global environment. You'd have to make your own package to "hide" these functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following - it works at the prompt but not tested in a startup script:

Create a new environment:

```
> e = new.env()
```

Create a quit function in that environment. Call `base::quit` to stop infinite loops:

```
> assign("quit",function(){base::quit()},envir=e)
```

at this point "quit" is still the base quit:

```
> quit
function (save = "default", status = 0, runLast = TRUE) 
.Internal(quit(save, status, runLast))
<bytecode: 0x55c7741932f8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

So we attach the environment:

```
> attach(e)
The following object is masked from package:base:

    quit
```

And now quit is our quit:

```
> quit
function(){base::quit()}
```

The only thing in our workspace is `e`:

```
> ls()
[1] "e"
```

But we can remove that:

```
> rm(e)
> ls()
character(0)
```

and still our `quit` is our `quit`:

```
> quit
function(){base::quit()}
```

because its attached, there's still a reference to it somewhere. I think. Anyway, try it.